# How to look for elements after rerender in React Testing Library?

Tags: react-testing-library

I have this piece of code where I destructure first `container` and `rerender` form rendering of Table. Then after a several steps I rerender the table. Then I check, using container if the value in component with testid `'selected-value'` is not what it was chosen before rerendering. But, the value persisted despite rerendering. Which means either that the Table was not rerendered or that the `container` is still referring to the `container` before rerender. I do not know how to look for the component with testid `'selected-value'` after rerendering.

```
  const { container, rerender } = render(<Table {...props} />)

  const select = container.querySelector("[data-testid='select']")

  fireEvent.click(select)

  const selectOption = container.querySelector("[data-testid='select-option']")
  const optionValue = selectOption.textContent

  fireEvent.click(selectOption)

  rerender(<Table {...props} />)

  expect(container.querySelector("[data-testid='selected-value']").textContent).toBe(lastValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am testing the scenario where Table needs to unmount and rerender completely from scratch but keeping in its state (or not keeping - depends on the setup) the value chosen in associated dropdown (for example on page refresh). To mimick this scenario I use the following code:

```
  const props = {
    rows,
    config
  }
  const { unmount } = render(<Table {...props} />)
  const select = screen.getByTestId('select')

  fireEvent.click(select)

  const selectOption = screen.getByTestId('select-option')
  const optionValue =  selectOption.textContent

  fireEvent.click(selectOption)

  unmount()
  render(<Table {...props} />)

  const selectedValue = screen.getByTestId('selected-value').textContent

  expect(selectedValue).toBe(optionValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The code below does not work since rerender() does not return anything.

You should perform the query in the new `container` returned by `rerender` (returns the same utilities as `render`).

```js
 const { container: newContainer } = rerender(<Table {...props} />)

  expect(newContainer.querySelector("[data-testid='dropdown-text-value']").textContent).not.toBe(lastValue)
```

###### Alternative approach using screen

You can also use the [screen](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#screen) object exposed by react-testing-library and since you are using test-ids perform all queries with `..ByTestId` selectors, without worrying about the updated `container`. Then your code would look like below

```js
import { screen } from '@react-testing-library/react'
...
rerender(<Table {...props} />)

expect(screen.getByTestId("dropdown-text-value").textContent).not.toBe(lastValue)
```

Comment: I tried with alternative approach and it did not work to my surprise. The first approach you suggest gives me this error: `Cannot read property 'container' of undefined` and it points to the container in line `const { container: newContainer } = rerender(<Table {...props} />)`

Comment: I think it is because `rerender` is a function so it returns by default `undefined`. It does not return any object, as the `render` does

Comment: interesting, i thought that it returned the same utilities as render. Does that `click` event you perform updates some state and that's why you want to rerender?

Comment: it updates the value in dropdown - on rerender this value should go to initial=default one

Comment: well, yes, you are right, the problem lies in state - it does not get updated with rerender, so the value from dropdown, selected before rerender, is still in the state in tests

Comment: probably this is due to the asynchronicity of state updates. When you perform the click event which eventually changes the state and then rerender you should probably [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) the changes to apply because they won't happen immediately

Comment: I tried with waitFor and it did not give the result - finally, in my tests I unmount the component and I remount it - I realized that the real app not only rerenders the component but also mounts it completely from scratch - so that was why simple rerendering it tests did not change the value

Comment: @bakrall what was the solution to the problem, please.

Comment: @IfeanyiChima I have just posted my solution